# mod_rewrite: rewrite everything to index.php without adding query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know there are thousands of thousands questions like this asked, but I can't seem to find an appropriate solution for my problem.

I'm trying to write a download script. The folder structure is like this:

- __admin/
- __uploads/
- index.php
- .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to redirect every single request to index.php as a parameter:

```
files.domain.com/awesomefile.zip -> files.domain.com/index.php?file=awesomefile.zip
```

This works as expected, but if I enter `http://files.domain.com/__admin` or `http://files.domain.com/admin` (without trailing slash), it gets rewritten to `http://files.domain.com/__admin/?file=__admin` respectively `http://files.domain.com/admin/?file=admin` (same with other existing dirs). I know that mod_dir could be the culprit, but setting `DirectorySlashes off` in .htaccess doesn't have any effect.

1. How do I get rid of the additional redirect (caused by mod_dir?) which adds the querystring to the URL? I want to completely hide the redirects from the user.
2. Why does it even affect `admin` (even though it isn't a directory)?

Edit: I'm sorry for being confusing, here are some examples which hopefully describe better what I mean:

- User types: `http://files.domain.com/file.zip`
  User sees: `http://files.domain.com/file.zip`
  Internal redirect: `http://files.domain.com/index.php?file=file.zip`
  This is the desired behaviour.
- User types: `http://files.domain.com/admin/` (note the trailing slash)
  User sees: `http://files.domain.com/admin/`
  Internal redirect: `http://files.domain.com/index.php?file=admin/`
- User types: `http://files.domain.com/admin`
  User sees: `http://files.domain.com/admin/?file=admin` <-- Why?
  Internal redirect: `http://files.domain.com/index.php?file=admin`

The last example shows my problem. I want to get rid of the query string which the user shouldn't see!

Comment: It affects everything, you've not specified any conditions, so absolutely every single request is being sent to index.php

Comment: Yeah that's what I want, but why is the querystring appended to `http://files.domain.com/admin` as well? It isn't a directory, and every other request works just fine.

Comment: Because you're telling it to.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I'm not telling mod_rewrite to add a querystring in the first place. The redirect with the querystring should be _internal_, and this is what works as expected, I'm able to get the parameter in my PHP script. But the user shouldn't see anything of it, if he enters `files.domain.com/awesomefile.zip`, his URL bar still shows exactly the same URL as he typed in, but if he types `http://files.domain.com/admin`, the querystring appears in his URL bar which shouldn't happen.

Comment: I think you are confusing terms.  The trailing slash is not a query string.  Nothing in your examples shows any additional query string values being appended after `?file=*` though you are using the query string append `[QSA]` flag such that if a URI like `admin?foo=bar` was passed you would get `index.php?file=admin&foo=bar`.  Not sure if this is desired behavior or not. Your question is confusing though when you are talking about query strings being appended and there are none in your example.

Comment: I've edited my question adding some examples to show what I mean.

Comment: @marank There has to be something more that you are showing to get this behavior. Are there any other server or directory level directives in server config files that are not being shown here?

Comment: The `RewriteRule` pattern `^(.*?)$` looks wrong (what is that `?` doing there?), shouldn't that simply be `(.*)`? Also, if you are rewriting to a relative substitution then you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in saying that `mod_dir` would add a trailing slash if the URI matches a directory name.  Thus is you had a URI like `/__admin` it would get rewritten to `/__admin/` since there is a directory of that name.  You can control this behavior.

You can change this behavior through the `DirectorySlash` directive

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Place this before your rewrite rules.

This still doesn't explain your example of `/admin` having the slash added. I would question whether this is reproducable.

Please note that security warning related to turning off DirectorySlash.  You could introduce a security vulnerability.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

Answer (score 1):

your rule is set that every request will be directed to the index page so this mean that requests to subfolders will be affected as well, you can specify in the rule what files need to be ignored from the rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|_admin)
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d` would be more elegant than listing out every single folder.